# Which jmx metric should be used to monitor the status of a connector in kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, metrics, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the following [jmx metrics](https://gist.github.com/jigar1101/ba02fef8c8a8ccb7550b75e95db2abcd) for kafka connect.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [Connect Monitoring](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_monitoring) section in the Kafka docs, it lists all the Kafka Connect specific metrics.

For example there are overall metrics for each connector:

- `kafka.connect:type=connector-metrics,connector="{connector}"` which contains a connector status (running, failed, etc)
- `kafka.connect:type=connector-task-metrics,connector="{connector}",task="{task}"` which contains the status of individual tasks

If you want more than just the status, there are also additional metrics for both sink and source tasks:

- `kafka.connect:type=connector-task-metrics,connector="{connector}",task="{task}"`
- `kafka.connect:type=sink-task-metrics,connector="{connector}",task="{task}"`

Comment: Thanks @Mickael! I checked the connect monitoring before posting the question but couldn't find the metrics specified in emitted metrics of jmx.
Can you check [this] (https://gist.github.com/jigar1101/ba02fef8c8a8ccb7550b75e95db2abcd) and let me know where would the above metric be in this emitted metrics.

Comment: There's no Connector metrics in your output. Do you have any Connectors in your Connect cluster ? Which version of Connect are you running ?

Comment: Yes I have connectors deployed in my Connect cluster. The version is  1.1.0-cp1
Any example of what connector metrics would be emitted? 
The list I have uploaded contains the metrics emitted when I do a curl request to the metrics api. (Without the numbers)

Comment: After your response stating no Connector metrics in my output, I checked the metrics again (Have updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jigar1101/ba02fef8c8a8ccb7550b75e95db2abcd))
I found that from the examples you mentioned above, ```connector-task-metrics, sink-task-metrics``` are now visible but still ```connector-metrics``` which contains the connector status and what I was looking for is not present. Any suggestions what I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't have enough rep to comment but I can answer...

Elaborating on Mickael's answer, **be careful:** currently task metrics **disappear** when a task is in a failed state rather than show up with the FAILED status. A [Jira can be found here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9066) and [PR can be found here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/8502)

Comment: This has been fixed since Kafka 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Connector status is available under kafka.connect:type=connector-metrics.
With [jmxterm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/manual.html), you may notice that the attributes are described as doubles instead of strings:

```
$>info
#mbean = kafka.connect:connector=dev-kafka-connect-mssql,type=connector-metrics
#class name = org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter$KafkaMbean
# attributes
  %0   - connector-class (double, r)
  %1   - connector-type (double, r)
  %2   - connector-version (double, r)
  %3   - status (double, r)

$>get status
#mbean = kafka.connect:connector=dev-kafka-connect-mssql,type=connector-metrics:
status = running;
```

This resulted in WARN logs from my monitoring agent:

```
    2018-05-23 14:35:53,966 | WARN | JMXAttribute | Unable to get metrics from kafka.connect:type=connector-metrics,connector=dev-kafka-connect-rabbitmq-orders - status
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "running"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.JMXAttribute.castToDouble(JMXAttribute.java:270)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.JMXSimpleAttribute.getMetrics(JMXSimpleAttribute.java:32)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.JMXAttribute.getMetricsCount(JMXAttribute.java:226)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.Instance.getMatchingAttributes(Instance.java:332)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.Instance.init(Instance.java:193)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App.instantiate(App.java:604)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App.init(App.java:658)
        at org.datadog.jmxfetch.App.main(App.java:140)
```

Each monitoring system may have different fixes, but I suspect the cause may be the same?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I couldn't find any logs related to the ones you mentioned.